# Messenger's Nicknames are changing simultaneously in one side .What's Wrong?

Tags: facebook, facebook-chat

Me and my friend are connected to Facebook messenger . We have changed our nicknames . but continuously at one side the nicknames are getting changed but another side its same as always . and also emojis are getting changed in one side only though me and my friend doesn't changed anything also there's no notify messages of modifications .. What's wrong ? How to solve this problem ?

At the picture you see at right(my messenger) nicknames are same but at left picture (friend's messenger) nicknames have changed

[image: show image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Messenger